# Delaying AngularJS route change until load page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use library "ui-router" in angular. I have problem in route page when I route to other page till when load controller last page show and at the same time 2 page show in one page and when load page, last page remove. 
How to solve problem delay ?

```
app.config([
"$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider",
function (stateProvider, urlRouterProvider) {


    urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");

    stateProvider
        .state("Dashboard",
        {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Dashboard/Partials/dashboard.html",
            controller: "DashboardCtrl as self"
        })
        .state("Deposit",
        {
            url: "/dashboard/desposit",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Dashboard/Partials/deposit.html",
            controller: "DepositCtrl as self"
        })
        .state("PeymentRequest",
        {
            url: "/dashboard/peymentRequest",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Dashboard/Partials/peymentRequest.html",
            controller: "PeymentRequestCtrl as self"
        })
        .state("ChangeBroker",
        {
            url: "/dashboard/changeBroker",
            templateUrl: "/Modules/Dashboard/Partials/changeBroker.html",
            controller: "ChangeBrokerCtrl as self"
        });
}
```

]);

Comment: _what a puzzle_. Can you at least show your angular.config with your states?

Comment: yes . I put it  under my question

Comment: that doesn't look like the right syntax or the use of nested views. You should have `controller:"DashboardCtrl", controllerAs: "self"`, and you should change states to something like `.state("Dashboard.Deposit", { url="/deposit", ...` then you can have `ui-view` in the dashboard with `ui-sref="Dashboard.Deposit"` links pointing to nested views

Comment: Can you put your answer as complete for me and use from it ? thanks

Comment: does problem delay solve when I use your answer ?

Comment: Here is a [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WWVhGqZpiKEkV6tEhmnj?p=preview) with the right syntax. Do you still have questions about this setup?

Comment: controllerAs not work ? I put your code in app.confg but it doesn't work

Comment: my code only shows the right syntax, it may not work with your setup if you just copy everything. Note that `templateUrl` is different. As for the `controllerAs`, it is case sensitive. Show what you have as well as any errors in the console